# css Button doesnt trigger event in float right

Tags: asp.net, css

i have a div floating right with 3 buttons on it and in the IE i can click every part of the button and he triggers the event but on the chrome i only can trigger in a small place of the button.

```
div class="ConfigButton">
                    <div >
                        <asp:Button ID="smallVS" runat="server" Text="Small" OnClick="small_Click"  CssClass="btType"/>
                    </div>
                    <div >
                        <asp:Button ID="mediumVS" runat="server" Text="Medium" OnClick="med_Click" CssClass="btType" ></asp:Button>
                    </div>  
                    <div >
                        <asp:Button ID="largeVS" runat="server" Text="Large" OnClick="large_Click" CssClass="btType" ></asp:Button> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .ConfigButton {
   float:right;
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-right:20px;

}

.ConfigButton div{
    clear:both;
}


.btType {

    font-size:18px;
    width:180px;
    height:40px;
    color:white;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    background-color:#4fc1dc;
    margin-bottom:30px;

}
```

I tried using `clear:both` but it didnt worked.

edit:[image: Example]

Comment: So you trying to create a divider and nesting 3 ASP buttons in it. Never seen that before. I do not think clear:both is an issue. Clear: both only clears elements on the left & right side of the divider

Comment: i did that way cause i wanted them vertical aligned.

Comment: Its hard for me to actually visualize this. Can u add an image or screenshot or actual link?

Comment: i added the image of how i want/have the buttons

Comment: Ok so basically you are saying that the button click event does not work in chrome? check this examplehttp://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2005/04/25/37630.aspx. it would be great to have a live demo or link so we can test this and help you

Comment: it works on chrome but only if i click a partial part of the button while on the IE i can click everywhere on the button that it ll trigger the event

Comment: Frankly speaking. your problem does seem very odd to me. Are you sure this is really an error with your code. Have you tried this on any other machine? unless we have a working example its difficult to make an assumption.

Comment: Just as a last try . Try removing the margin property for the button in CSS ---> margin-bottom:30px;  THis bit.  remove this and check

Comment: it didnt worked, i can only trigger in chrome if i click below the text, its like the button is 1px